# SVN: Is upgrade working copy safe?

Tags: svn

I have upgraded eclipse to Luna (from Juno). Almost all repositories i have in Git right now, but one is older and it is Subversion. Eclipse SVN client force me to upgrade working copy for that repo. It is safe for other commiters (that may have older SVN client) ?

> org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: The working copy needs
>   to be upgraded svn: The working copy at 'C:\dev\workspace\proj-svn' is
>   too old (format 10) to work with client version '1.8.11 (r1643975)'
>   (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's safe. SVN server is still unchanged, and that's all that matters.

Comment: Server SVN is rather old. Could i make commits after that and my commits dont break the repo ? I'm not familiar with SVN.

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure it's safe. Clents are made to work with old servers. Server will not "brake" if you change the client. The only problem could be that your new client might not work properly in some obscure edge cases, but server data will remain safe.